# How to get all sublists as output if input matches with an element of sublist in nested lists

Tags: python-2.7, nested-lists

Below code is to get sublist as output if input matches with an element of sublist. 37.21 is matched twice but gives one sublist as output. How to get both sublists in output

```
nested_list = [['A', 37.21], ['B', 37.21], ['C', 37.2], ['D', 41], ['E', 39]]
match = 37.21
def search_nested(mylist, val):
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        for j in range(len(mylist[i])):
            #print i,j
            if mylist[i][j] == val:
                return mylist[i]
print search_nested(nested_list, match)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nested_list = [['A', 37.21], ['B', 37.21], ['C', 37.2], ['D', 41], ['E', 39]]
match = 37.21
for i in nested_list:
    if match in i:
        print(i)
```

Comment: if you want you can put that for loop in a method returning i instead of printing directly;

Comment: Thank you Drako !

Comment: If it works mark as answer, please, otherwise its floating in SO as unanswered question and I already hate when browsing unanswered questions to find out that 80% of them are actually answered just wasting professionals time because author could not mark it respectively ...

Comment: I already upvoted it.But its not visible due to my reputation. Is there something else i need to do?

Comment: accept the answer, there should be button near the answer (tick right under up-vote/down-vote buttons)

Comment: still looks like not accepted :) does not matter; most important - it worked for you and helped; let this bug or whatever be fixed by someone with certain rights on SO